# Remove array entry with one or more duplicate values in multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

How can I remove an array entry with one or more duplicate values in multidimensional array? For example if I have:

```
array (size=4)
 0 => 
    array (size=3)
      'food' => string 'bread' (length=5)
      'color' => string 'white' (length=5)
      'language' => string 'php' (length=3)
  1 => 
    array (size=3)
      'food' => string 'rice' (length=4)
      'color' => string 'purple' (length=6)
      'language' => string 'c#' (length=2)
  2 => 
    array (size=3)
      'food' => string 'pasta' (length=5)
      'color' => string 'red' (length=3)
      'language' => string 'php' (length=3)
  3 => 
    array (size=3)
      'food' => string 'steak' (length=5)
      'color' => string 'yellow' (length=6)
      'language' => string 'ruby' (length=4)
```

Since there is a php entry in array[2], I want to delete the entire record so that I can have

```
array (size=4)
 0 => 
    array (size=3)
      'food' => string 'bread' (length=5)
      'color' => string 'white' (length=5)
      'language' => string 'php' (length=3)
  1 => 
    array (size=3)
      'food' => string 'rice' (length=4)
      'color' => string 'purple' (length=6)
      'language' => string 'c#' (length=2)
  2 => 
    array (size=3)
      'food' => string 'steak' (length=5)
      'color' => string 'yellow' (length=6)
      'language' => string 'ruby' (length=4)
```

I have tried this code:

```
array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $array)));
```

and it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your objects are all different (for instance, they all have different colors), `array_unique` will not reduce the number of elements.

Instead, key your array elements by their `language` property: that will eliminate duplicate `php` entries, and then convert that associated array back to an indexed one:

```
foreach($array as $row) {
    $result[$row['language']] = $row;
}
$result = array_values($result);
```

Comment: This is awesome!

Answer (score 0):

The solution using `array_intersect` and `array_merge` functions (will cover duplicates for all keys):

```
$arr = [
    ['food' => 'bread', 'color' => 'white', 'language' => 'php'],
    ['food' => 'rice', 'color' => 'purple', 'language' => 'c#'],
    ['food' => 'pasta', 'color' => 'red', 'language' => 'php'],
    ['food' => 'steak', 'color' => 'yellow', 'language' => 'ruby']
];

$values = [];  // auxiliary array
foreach ($arr as $k => $a) {
    if (array_intersect($values, $a)){
        unset($arr[$k]);  // removing the whole `entry` if it contains duplicates in any key
    } else {
        $values = array_merge($values, array_values($a));
    }
}

print_r($arr);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [food] => bread
            [color] => white
            [language] => php
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [food] => rice
            [color] => purple
            [language] => c#
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [food] => steak
            [color] => yellow
            [language] => ruby
        )
)
```

Comment: @Nan, you have already accepted the answer. So ask your question to that peaople